# AWS IAM Python Boto3 script - Create User

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3, aws-cli

My Issue: I am trying to create an AWS CLI script using Python and the Boto3 library. I want the script to ask for inputs (username? programmatic access? attach to which Group? Change password on first login? etc.) and set up the user with those details.

My Attempt: I can create the user and give the user programmatic access or not.
My problem lies with passing the selected Group ARN to the attach_group_policy PolicyARN='aws:aws:iam::aws:policy/xxxx

I feel a veriable suits here but cannot think how to do it. Hopefully my code below shows my problem better.

```
iam = boto3.resource('iam')
iam_keys = boto3.resource('iam')
group_list = boto3.client('iam')
attach_group = boto3.client('iam')

mail = raw_input("Please enter your e-mail address: ")
response = iam.create_user(UserName=mail)

prog = raw_input("Do you require programmatic access?(y/n): ") 
if prog == "y":
        iam_keys.create_access_key(UserName=mail)
        print("Make sure awscli is installed on your machine")
elif prog == "n":
        print("Console access only")


### it is this area downwards that things break/get confusing
list = group_list.list_groups(MaxItems=150)   ### works
for "GroupName" in list:                      ### works
        print(list)                           ### works; prints as large JSON, need to output just u' GroupName

float(input("Please pick a Group {}".format(attach)))

var = attach_group.attach_group_policy(GroupName=attach, PolicyArn='aws:aws:iam::aws:policy/xxxx')     ### Broke; need to fill in ARN somehow after forward slash

print(response, prog)
```

I want the selected Policy (selected by typing exact name of Group) to attach to the user.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I have very little Python knowledge nad have been following https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a Python 2 example of how to list IAM groups, allow the user to select one of them, and then use the ARN corresponding to the selected IAM group:

```
import boto3

iam = boto3.client('iam')

rsp = iam.list_groups()
groups = rsp['Groups']
print(groups)
index = 1

for group in groups:
  print("%d: %s" % (index, group["GroupName"]))
  index += 1

option = int(input("Please pick a group number: "))
arn = groups[option-1]["Arn"]
print("You selected group %d: %s" % (option, arn))
```

Or in Python3:

```
import boto3

iam = boto3.client('iam')

rsp = iam.list_groups()
groups = rsp['Groups']
index = 1

for group in groups:
    print(f'{index}: {group["GroupName"]}')
    index += 1

option = int(input("Please pick a group number: "))
arn = groups[option-1]["Arn"]
print(f'You selected group {option}: {arn}')
```

This will result in something like this:

```
1: admins
2: devops
3: programmers
Please pick a group number: 2
You selected option 2: arn:aws:iam::123456781234:group/devops
```

Note: you will need to add input validation around this, for example if the user types -3 or the letter A.

If, as I suspect, you actually need the user to select a policy by name so that you can retrieve the ARN for that policy (to attach to an IAM group), then you can do that as follows:

```
rsp = iam.list_policies(Scope='Local', OnlyAttached=False)
policies = rsp['Policies']
index = 1

for policy in policies:
    print("%d: %s" % (index, policy["PolicyName"]))
    index += 1

option = int(input("Please pick a policy number: "))
arn = policies[option-1]["Arn"]
print("You selected policy %d: %s" % (option, arn))
```

Comment: thank you very much, but unfortunately doesn't work. I should mention I am running Python2.7 (cannot change). Output;
$ python ec2-play.py
File "ec2-play.py", line 28
print(f'{index}: {group["GroupName"]}')

Comment: removing the f in print() gives me output but it is outputting plain text and crashes;
$ python ec2-play.py 
Please enter your e-mail address: 1@2.ie
Do you require programmatic access?(y/n): n
Console access only
{index}: {group["GroupName"]}
{index}: {group["GroupName"]}
{index}: {group["GroupName"]}
Please pick a Group number: 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ec2-play.py", line 32, in <module>
    arn = list[option-1]["Arn"]
KeyError: 1

Comment: It should be easy to convert print statements to Python2 but I've added that above.

Comment: thank you so much, this works. Although it doesn't attach yet, I will work on that now. Appreciate the help big time!

Comment: For attachment, you provide the GroupName that you want to attach a policy to, and the ARN of the policy that you want to attach to that group. So you're not actually using the group ARN here, you need the group *name* and the policy *ARN*.

Comment: Following on from your P2.7 example, I have tried and failed the following from last night and this morning, hate to come here again straying from original issue:

print("You selected option %d: %s" % (option, arn))
var = "%s" % (arn)
var.split(":group/")[1]
g = var[1]
final = grp.add_user_to_group(GroupName=g, UserName=mail)
print("User has been added to Group you selected")

Comment: It’s best to add code to the original post (or a new Stack Overflow post) but what is the current problem? You said it failed, but that’s not enough information. The selected group name is available at groups[option-1][“GroupName”]. You don’t have to parse it from the ARN.

Comment: I was wondering why the small comments section was so cramped! I have posted a new Q, cheers!! @jarmod https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56685602/aws-iam-python-script-add-new-user-to-existing-group