# AWS IAM Python script - Add new User to existing Group

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3

**Context:** I have a Python script that can create a User, decide on programmatic access or not, list the current Groups for Users. **My issue is** that I wish to add the new User to one of the existing, shown Groups.

I have tried the code below but get the following error:

```py
python ec2-play.py
Please enter your e-mail address: 1@1.com
Do you require programmatic access?(y/n): n
Console access only
[...list of Groups...]
1: admin-short-term
2: aws-admin
3: aws-admin-mfa
4: aws-training
Please pick a Group number: 4
You selected option 4: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:group/aws-training
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ec2-play.py", line 41, in <module>
    final = grp.add_user_to_group(GroupName=g, UserName=mail)
  File "/opt/axe/local/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 314, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/opt/axe/local/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 612, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.NoSuchEntityException: An error occurred (NoSuchEntity) when calling the AddUserToGroup operation: The group with name r cannot be found.
```

This the code that produces that error output:

```py
import boto3

iam = boto3.resource('iam')
iam_keys = boto3.resource('iam')
group_list = boto3.client('iam')
attach_group = boto3.client('iam')
grp = boto3.client("iam")

mail = raw_input("Please enter your e-mail address: ")
response = iam.create_user(UserName=mail)

prog = raw_input("Do you require programmatic access?(y/n): ") 
if prog == "y":
        iam_keys.create_access_key(UserName=mail)
        print("Make sure awscli is installed on your machine")
elif prog == "n":
        print("Console access only")

list = group_list.list_groups()
groups = list['Groups']
print(groups)
index = 1

for group in groups:
        print("%d: %s" % (index, group["GroupName"]))
        index +=1

option = int(input("Please pick a Group number: "))
arn = groups[option-1]["Arn"]
print("You selected option %d: %s" % (option, arn))

var = "%s" % (arn)
var.split(":group/")[1]

g = var[1]

final = grp.add_user_to_group(GroupName=g, UserName=mail)

print("User has been added to Group %s you selected" % (g))
```

**Expected behavior:** New User gets attached the selected Group.
**Actual behavior:** Python crashes out saying Group r cannot be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already calculated which group was selected - it's the `option-1`'th element in the `groups` list. You can retrieve any of its attributes in the normal way, for example:

```
group = groups[option-1]
group_name = group["GroupName"]
group_arn = group["Arn"]
```

Instead of calculating and using `g`, simply use `groups[option-1][“GroupName”]` for the group name (or `group_name` as calculated above).

The bigger picture here is that you’re going to need to learn how to debug your code. Printing out values as you go along (var and g, for example) and comparing them to what you expected to see is one way. A source-level debugger is another way.